# Meaning of “In Final Break”

Tags: meaning, headlinese

> Trump Fires John Bolton In Final Break After Months Of Internal Policy Division
>
> —[NPR](https://www.npr.org/2019/09/10/724363700/trump-fires-john-bolton-in-final-break-after-months-of-policy-divisions), September 10, 2019

What does "in Final Break" mean here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Headlines can be strange

This is headline-speak — or on ELL, [headlinese](/questions/tagged/headlinese). Headlines in news articles have their own set of grammar rules which can be very different from formal written English, in particular:

- Articles (“a, an, the”) are almost always omitted
- “And” is almost always omitted

When you see the headline:

> Trump Fires John Bolton In Final Break After Months Of Internal Policy Division

You have to unpack (uncompress) it.

### An Interpretation

> 1) After months of internal policy division...

“Division” here means [arguments or disagreements](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/topics/expressing-opposition-and-disapproval/arguments-and-disagreements/).

> 2) Trump Fires John Bolton..

I’ll let you consult [“Politics” Stack Exchange](https://politics.stackexchange.com/) for a further discussion of this.

> 3) in {**a**} final break.

The “break” is a breakup (or **[separation](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/break)**) of two people who worked closely together.

It’s {**a**} *final* break because, the headline says, it comes after many disagreements.   It is the final resolution of (the headline says) a long-term problem between the two individuals.

The word “a” has been omitted from the headline, and the order of parts 1-2-3 changed, to pack more words into a smaller space.   This is how headlines are often done in English-language news services.